# Returning complex types (Classes, Arrays of Classes) using JCL and CLR

Tags: delphi, clr, delphi-xe, jedi-code-library

I first referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048540/hosting-clr-in-delphi-with-without-jcl-example) to get started, but reached a roadblock when trying to return a **Class** or **Array of a Class** using a .NET Assembly in Delphi XE.

Consider the following:

```
//C#
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Person {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class SomeClass 
{
    public SomeClass() {}        

    public Person[] GetPersons()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

//Delphi
type TPerson = class
  Id : Integer;
  Name : string;
end;
```

How do I make sense of the data that is returned from `GetPersons()` which I can assign to an `array of TPerson` in Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not that way.  Delphi and .NET have different object models, and different string types, which aren't compatible with each other.  If you want to pass objects between .NET and Delphi modules, the best way is probably to use COM.

Comment: +1 for "Delphi and .NET have different object models, and different string types, which aren't compatible with each other"

Comment: Are you able to provide a link with examples? I do not have any experience using COM.