# Can .netCore DLL use from native code like C++/Delphi

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, dll, .net-core

.netCore v1.1 has ClassLibrary Project and it will compile to a DLL

Is this DLL is unmanaged? and can i call it from C++ or Delphi?

Comment: No, that DLL is managed and you can't call it from C++ or Delphi. You can, however, add a non portable interface library where you may export COM objects (write it in C++/CLI, C# and any other .NET language and consume them from almost any language, including C++ and Delphi). Alternatively write this library in C++/CLI and you can export plain C functions.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks. I use other methods like [Robert Giesecke](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) but was wondering can i use .netCore or not.

Comment: I don't know if that package is compatible with .NET Core 1.1, if I should guess I'd say...no but nothing is better than trying!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you are right. this package is compatible with .net not .netCore. I means use this package and .net for make DLL

Comment: The first comment outlines your options quite clearly

Comment: See also https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

Comment: @ondrej The discussion above concerns UnmanagedExports, which seems not to be for .net core.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to host .NET environment inside your code.

In Delphi you may use `TJclClrHost` class from `JclDotNet.pas` unit (Jedi Code Library).

PS The classes in your DLL may be not `ComVisible` so you may need to use reflection  to make the call. See "using reflection" sample from [Hosting CLR in Delphi with/without JCL - example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048540/hosting-clr-in-delphi-with-without-jcl-example)

Comment: This question is about .NET Core, not .NET itself.