# How to make a .net(c#) library which can be used in delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, com, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a C# DLL That Can Be Imported in a Delphi App Using stdcall - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063151/create-a-c-dll-that-can-be-imported-in-a-delphi-app-using-stdcall-possible)

I am creating a c# library and like to make this library as com component which can be accessed from delphi. Please tell the how to achieve this.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063151/create-a-c-dll-that-can-be-imported-in-a-delphi-app-using-stdcall-possible/1063231#1063231 (and probably many others)

Answer (score 3):

How to make .Net (C#) classes accessible through COM is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-dotnet-components-to-com). Basicly your classes need to have a default constructor without parameters and you need to decorate your classes with some specific attributes. Then you need to register your assembly using regasm.

Then you can import the ActiveX/COM library in Delphi and call it like it was a regular ActiveX/COM Library.

Answer (score 0):

I won't rewrite, but there is a solution on how to do this here : http://forums.devshed.com/delphi-programming-90/c-dll-need-to-be-used-in-delphi-231122.html

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to using VB instead of C# there's a cleaner solution. In VB you can use the ComClass item template which does virtually all the work to expose your .NET type to COM for you.