# Can we call .net(2.0) dll from Delphi 5 application

Tags: .net, delphi

Can we call a dll built in .Net2.0 from Delphi 5 windows application. If yes, how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosting the .NET runtime in a Delphi Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258875/hosting-the-net-runtime-in-a-delphi-program)

Answer (score 7):

You could expose this .NET assembly as COM object using the [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) tool:

```
regasm.exe /tlb /codebase Foo.dll
```

For this to work your assembly (or the type you are willing to expose as COM object) needs to be marked with the [`[ComVisible(true)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute.

Then you could consume it as you would consume a normal COM object from Delphi: by importing the type library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.managed-vcl.com/
I have been working with this component and it is really easy to use and very fast. It worked on all assemblies I have tested so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CrossTalk](http://www.atozed.com/CrossTalk/).

Comment: Remmy `CrossTalk` supports Delphi 2007 and higher, http://www.atozed.com/CrossTalk/FAQ/index.EN.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.